# jQuery button toggle text not working onclick

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide and show content on click which I have managed to do with a  simple toggle effect, but I also want the button's text to toggle. So when it loads it reads "click here to view classes" then on click it reveals the content and switches the text on the button to read "Click to hide classes"

here is my js fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/44wdatL9/

I have taken this code out, it only seemed to change the text on the first click and not toggle it back.

```
$(".class-list").toggle(function() {
    $(this).text("Click here to view classes");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("Click to hide classes");
});
```

Comment: FYI, `toggle()` event has been removed from jq 1.9, use click event instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways to do this without using .toggle() one of them is here

```
 var clicks = true;
    $('.class-list').click(function() {
      if (clicks) {
        $(this).text("Click here to view classes");
        clicks = false;
      } else {
        $(this).text("Click here to Hide classes");
        clicks = true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple buttons then you may assign css class i.e "classesVisible" and on click toggle the class of that particular item and change its text accordingly.